# Почему flex-wrap не делает обтекание сбоку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, почему нижний блок не обтекает сбоку кнопку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -3%;
  margin-right: -3%;
}
.item{
  width: 33%;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}
.item span{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>2</span></div>
        <div class="item"><span>3</span></div>
        <div class="item"><button>click</button></div>
        <div class="item1">
            <p>Нажимая на кнопку, вы даете согласие на обработку персональных данных и соглашаешься с 
                <a target="blank" href="#">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Если задать ширину нижнему блоку, тогда блок встаёт сбоку. Но, ширину нельзя задавать - она может быть разная.
Если убрать ссылку, тогда также нормально обтекает сбоку.

Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Перенесите параграф внутрь дива с кнопкой и задайте параграфу и диву display: inline-block

Comment: @Samoedy это не совсем решает проблему, потому-что текст начинает обтекать сбоку, но у кнопки ширина не 33% а меньше

Comment: Если у флекс-блока нет ширины, то он растягивается адаптивно (в зависимости от его наполнения). Он растягивается на всю длину, не умещается в оставшееся пространство и, соответственно, падает на следующкю строку. Пропишите ему максимальную ширину.

Comment: @NoSkill, max-width также не решает полностью проблему, на мобильных будет потом сложно адаптировать без js

Comment: Хотите вы или нет, это так работает. Для мобильных существует media-query, кто в 2021 растягивает блоки с помощью js? Более того у флекса есть shrink и grow.